# SSH refusing connections after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: server, 13.10, upgrade, ssh

After upgrading my Ubuntu Server from release 13.04 to 13.10 (`do-release-upgrade`), I can not connect to the server anymore, SSH closing connections immediately (after sending SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT). It worked well before upgrade and restart of the server.

```
~$ ssh -v superuser@MYHOST
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
[...]
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 123.123.123.123
```

As I had versioned the system configuration files, I can see that `/etc/hosts.allow`, `/etc/hosts.deny` did not change, nor did `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

I checked some similar questions on AskUbuntu, StackExchange and SuperUser, but none of them solves this case, so I'm submitting it again.

A few issues I checked:

1. [AskUbuntu · Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 broke remote SSH access? · 10.11.2013](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374858/upgrade-from-13-04-to-13-10-broke-remote-ssh-access)
2. [Superuser · Not able to connect with server. Connection closed by remote server · 10.08.2013](https://superuser.com/questions/630281/not-able-to-connect-with-server-connection-closed-by-remote-server)
3. [StackOverflow · SSH: Connection closed by remote server · 08.08.2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120956/ssh-connection-closed-by-remote-server?rq=1)
4. [StackOverflow · ssh connection stop at “debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent” [closed] · 4.03.2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419412/ssh-connection-stop-at-debug1-ssh2-msg-kexinit-sent)

Comment: Try connecting with very verbose `ssh -vvv name@remote` to see if the additional output reveals anything.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried it, but it did not reveal anything more useful. I solved the issue in the meantime, which was related to the permissions of the private key files in /etc/ssh/ on the server. I'll post a detailed answer in a couple of hours;  I can't for now, not having enough karma out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining the log file `/var/log/auth.log` on the server, to which I connected thru the KVM-over-IP console, I found out that the SSH daemon was ignoring the server private key files `ssh_host_rsa_key`, `ssh_host_dsa_key`, `ssh_host_ecdsa_key`, while complaining about their permissions:

```
# tail -f /var/log/auth.log
[…]
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: @         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: Permissions 0644 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key' are too open.
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: This private key will be ignored.
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: bad permissions: ignore key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Feb 21 13:49:18 MYHOST sshd[14646]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
[…]
```

I restricted the permissions and restarted the SSH daemon, which solved my issue:

```
# cd /etc/ssh
# chmod go-r *
# initctl restart ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was happening because of incorrect MTU settings while using a PPTP vpn. This fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo ip link set ppp0 mtu 1400
```